# Is there an equivalent to SHA1() in MS-SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, sha1, t-sql, sql-server

Converting a couple stored procedures from MySQL to Microsoft SQL server. Everything is going well, except one procedure used the MySQL `SHA1()` function. I cannot seem to find an equivalent to this in MS-SQL.

Does anyone know a valid equivalent for `SHA1()` on MS-SQL?

Comment: If this is for password storage, I feel compelled to mention that simply hashing the raw string is not good enough in most cases.  Here's why: http://www.md5decrypter.co.uk/sha1-decrypt.aspx   ... among many others...  There are tons of rainbow tables out there and reversing an un-salted password is pretty trivial these days because of it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 and later has the [HashBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function.

Comment: Looks perfect, answered while I took a leak. I love stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: Now if they'd just get support for a 256-bit algo instead of only 160

Answer (score 32):

If you want to get a SHA1 hash exactly as MySQL would generate it (i.e. as a varchar), you can combine HashBytes with sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring. E.g.

```
SELECT sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', 'password'), 1, 0)
```

See http://accessrichard.blogspot.co.nz/2010/12/sql-server-and-net-equivalent-to-php.html for more details.

Answer (score 5):

MSSQL Server

```
HASHBYTES('SHA1', CAST('abcd@#' as nvarchar(max)))
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA1', CAST('abcd@#' as nvarchar(max))) , 2)

/* result */
0x77DD873DBAB2D81786AB9AE6EA91B1F59980E48C  
77DD873DBAB2D81786AB9AE6EA91B1F59980E48C
```

C#

```
using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
{
    string input = "abcd@#";
    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input));
    var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
    
    foreach (byte b in hash)
    {
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2")); // can be "x2" if you want lowercase
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
//result "77DD873DBAB2D81786AB9AE6EA91B1F59980E48C"
```

Comment: Nice. Binary style `2` of `CONVERT` returns VARCHAR without `0x`.

Answer (score 2):

From google groups - [A Possibility](http://groups.google.de/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/browse_thread/thread/caf7e350f09c5689/16b6f95a74eda0ce)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check out http://www.stev.org/post/2011/01/30/MS-SQL-SHASum-Support.aspx you should be able to modify it to produce anything you want. Though some c# coding may be required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's native support, but you may want to check this out...

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlcat/archive/2005/09/16/469257.aspx